# Issue with Nested Form rendering

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ruby, forms

I have a rails 4 app that has a form that looks like:

```
<%= form_for @store, :html => {:multipart => true} do |f| %>
  <%= f.fields_for :products do |product| %>
    <%= render partial: "edit_product_fields", locals: {product:product} %>
  <% end %>
  <%= f.submit %>
<% end %>
```

and the edit_product_fields partial looks like:

```
<select>
   <option value="Textbook" <% if product.type_of == "Textbook" %>selected<% end %>>Textbook</option>
   <option value="Magazine" <% if product.type_of == "Magazine" %>selected<% end %>>Magazine</option>
   <option value="Book"     <% if product.type_of == "Book"     %>selected<% end %>>Book</option>
</select>
```

When I have the code like this, I get the error:

```
undefined method `type_of' for #<NestedForm::Builder:0x00000102304f78>
```

but if I change the render line to (I just made it less explicit by taking out *partial:*):

```
<%= render "edit_product_fields", locals: {product:product} %>
```

I get the error:

```
undefined local variable or method `product' for #<#<Class:0x0000010235a248>:0x0000010684b3c0>
```

Comment: I wonder how well is this gem maintained. last time I tried using `nested_form`, it didn't work for me. So I opted for `cocoon` gem

Comment: @WaliAli I don't think the OP is referring to a gem here, just the concept of nested attributes.

Comment: @pdobb you are probably right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your first code block, you have a `Builder` object being stored as `product`.

Fortunately, `Builder` provides an `object` method so you can access the actual object that it's representing in the form:

```
<select>
   <option value="Textbook" <%= 'selected' if product.object.type_of == "Textbook" %>>Textbook</option>
   <option value="Magazine" <%= 'selected' if product.object.type_of == "Magazine" %>>Magazine</option>
   <option value="Book"     <%= 'selected' if product.object.type_of == "Book"     %>>Book</option>
</select>
```

Comment: thanks for the response. I tried this, but got `undefined method type_of for #<Class:0x000001064bcf60>`

Comment: As I pointed out, try `product.object.class.name` or `product.object.is_a? Textbook` instead of `type_of`. I'm not even sure if `type_of` exists in Ruby or Rails.

Comment: Oops, I should have read better, sorry. `type_of` is a field in my product model. This code doesn't give me an error, but for the select I'm trying to say "If product.type_of is equal to Textbook, then make it selected". I should have been more clear, sorry about that.

Comment: No problem. I thought you were trying to mix JavaScript `typeof` with Ruby somehow. :)

Answer (score 2):

Well `type_of` is not a ruby method. It looks like it's an attempt to type check though... But type checking is generally frowned upon in duck-typed languages. At any rate, we can take advantage of a [Rails Form Helper](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/form_helpers.html#making-select-boxes-with-ease) instead and make this code a one-liner. But first...

The reason the `render` is complaining about `undefined local variable or method`product'` after your change is because the render call expects either the first argument to be a partial name and the second to be a hash of locals:

```
<%= render "partial_name", local1: "a", local2: "b" %>
```

... or it expects the the whole thing to be a hash:

```
<%= render partial: "partial_name", locals: { local1: "a", local2: "b" } %>
```

Now, back to the form helper.

What you're looking for here is the [select](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormBuilder.html#method-i-select) helper. This makes the following possible:

```
<%= product.select :type_of, %w[Textbook Magazine Book] %>
```

And this will render all of the same html as you've put into your `_edit_product_field.html.erb` partial. So you should probably just get rid of the partial to save on rendering time and put this directly into your form.

One other, minor point. It may be less confusing to call the `fields_for` block variable `product_form` instead of `product`. This is to help keep in mind that this is not a Product object you're dealing with, but rather a Form Generator object. Also, you don't need to specify `:multipart => true` in Rails 4 forms -- Rails knows to make the form multi-part if you have a file upload element within the form body.

So putting it all together:

```
<%= form_for @store do |f| %>
  <%= f.fields_for :products do |product_form| %>
    <%= product_form.select :product, %w[Textbook Magazine Book] %>
  <% end %>
  <%= f.submit %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: I should have been more clear. `type_of` is actually a field in my product model. I'll change my question to reflect that, sorry.

Comment: This is a better approach, but it should be `<%= product_form.select :type_of, %w[Textbook Magazine Book] %>`. Then I think you have a winner!